# I have to make a slicer with two option "Top 5" and "All Others" which should give me results as mentioned below

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have to make a slicer to pick rows from this data (i.e. if I choose top 5 option in slicer than all the top 5 rows for each value of column A should appear and if I choose all other option from slicer then all the values except top should appear). Let me explain you by table
Here is the data table

[image]

Our slicer will have two options one "Top 5" and another "All Others".
If I choose top 5 then i should get a table like below mentioned:

[image]

And If I choose "All Other Option in Slicer then I should get the Following Table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure with below code and use it as filter on your visual.

```
Filter_Measure = 
IF (
    (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer_Value[selection] ) = "Top 5"
            && MAX ( 'Table'[Rank] ) <= 5
    )
        || (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer_Value[selection] ) = "All Others"
                && MAX ( 'Table'[Rank] ) > 5
        ),
    1,
    0
)
```

PFA screenshot of visual with filter

[image]